# Complex regex separator in java

Tags: regex, split, separator

I would like to split a String with a very specific separator.
ex. Text :

> hello%!%!%;toto%!%;titi%!%!%;tata%;big%;level!%%;popo

The separator must be "%;" and have to be:

- specifically in this order
- not preceded by %!

So in this example, my split would return :
[hello%!%!%;toto%!%;titi%!%!%;tata] [big] [level!%] [popo]

Up until now, my regex looks like this :

> [^%!](%;)

But it doesn't match the last separator and the fisrt two also match the character before %;

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[^%!]` is a character class, i.e. it matches only one char that can be anything except `%` or `!`. You probably need a negative lookbehind instead: `(?<!%!)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote `[^%!]`. That means: any character not in the list `%!`. That's not what you want.

You can use a negative "look behind" expression: `(?<!...)` where `...` is the matching pattern

So your whole regex would be: `(?<!%!)(%;)`